# Regular expression - regex - matching

Tags: regex, invoice

How do I make an expression to match this below: (including spaces , whitespaces, other characters in the numbers)? Example:

```
asdasd (S)FS-980/24/BS/02 , asdasd

ffff (S)FS-9525/23/BS/12ss, IP000003587

FSW-952/24/BSB/02

FS-2/24/F/02

FS-4444/23/F/11
```

I mean if invoice number : `FS -444 4/23/F/11` - it also correct to: `FS-4444/23/F/11`, or `FS-4444g/23g/F/1g1`

i try like this: `...FS(W)-../.{2}/..(.)/\s.{2}`

Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/bq7lIM/3

Comment: Not sure what you want to match, but like this? `(?:\([A-Z]+\))?FS[A-Z ]*-\d(?:[^\n,()-]*\w)?` https://regex101.com/r/hxjCox/1

Comment: thanks,is any option to change founded output from: (S)FSK-69/23/GFK/ 1 2 to
(S)FSK-69/23/GFK/12 and  FS-4444g/23g/F/1g1 to FS-4444/23g/F/11 ?

Comment: If the amount and position of the unwanted characters are random, then you could for example remove them from the match in a second step. What is the tool or programming language that you are using?

Comment: i use RegexStringValidator Class from NET (microsoft)

Comment: @arczitje1000 Then you could do a second replacement with an empty string over the matched strings `(?<=^FS-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)[a-z]|[\p{Zs}\ta-z](?=[a-zA-Z0-9\p{Zs}\t]*$)` See https://regex101.com/r/ozJXHI/1 but it depends on the logic which parts of the match are allowed to keep the lowercase a-z and which parts are not.

Comment: thanks a lot, how i can connect these two codes ? (the first to extract the invoices, the second to clear them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could update your pattern to get the matches first. Then do a replacement over those matches, and remove the characters that you don't want.

To match the strings:

```
(?:\([A-Z]+\))?FS[A-Z ]*-\d(?:[^\n,()-]*\w)?
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:\([A-Z]+\))?` Optionally match `(` followed by 1+ chars A-Z and then `)`
- `FS[A-Z ]*-` match `FS` followed by optional chars A-Z or spaces
- `\d` Match a digit
- `(?:[^\n,()-]*\w)?` Optionally match any char except what is listed in the character class, and end on a word character

If you want to match a space without a newline in C# you can also use `\p{Zs}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hxjCox/1)

To replace the unwanted characters over the matched parts:

```
(?<=^FS-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)[a-z]|[\p{Zs}\ta-z](?=[a-zA-Z0-9\p{Zs}\t]*$)
```

This pattern will match all lowercase characters at the beginning of the string before the `-` and match all lowercase chars a-z or spaces at the end of the string, not crossing any characters other then what is listed in the character class present in the positive lookahead assertion.

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ozJXHI/1) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/q2zVev).

```
string patternMatch = @"(?:\([A-Z]+\))?FS[A-Z ]*-\d(?:[^\n,()-]*\w)?";
string patternReplace = @"(?<=^FS-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)[a-z]|[\p{Zs}\ta-z](?=[a-zA-Z0-9\p{Zs}\t]*$)";
string input = @"Fakturasadas : (S)FSK-69/23/GFK/12hjkhjkddddd
(S)FSK-69/23/GFK/ 1 2 
(S)FSK-69/23/GFK/12";

var strings = Regex
    .Matches(input, patternMatch)
    .Cast<Match>().Select(match => {                    
        return Regex.Replace(
            match.Value,
            patternReplace,
            ""
        );
    }
);

foreach (var s in strings) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output

```
(S)FSK-69/23/GFK/12
(S)FSK-69/23/GFK/12
(S)FSK-69/23/GFK/12
```